# What is an Offloaded SQL server?

Tags: vps, sql, kvm-virtualization

My job has pushed me far along enough to build a web app on a VPS.

I've decided to go with an unmanaged KVM VPS through http://buyvm.net

There are some features that I am unfamiliar with. I can not find anywhere to explain what this means:

> For an additional $1.00/month, customers may purchase access to an
>   offloaded MySQL server located on the same LAN as your VPS server.
>
> Our SQL servers are backed by RAID 10 + SSD read caching to
>   drastically improve performance.

Thoughts?

Comment: I assume this means they're giving you access to a shared MySQL server (so your server doesn't have the extra overhead of running SQL *and* the webapp) -- you should really ask your provider though.  Whether or not it makes sense is a judgment call you need to make based on your intended use, workload, security needs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask them for the details, but it looks like it is another VM, which happens to be on hardware slightly tuned for DB usage.